# QApplication in Shared Library

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa

I have minimal example of a program. It functions when compiled as an app, but fails as a shared library. Why is this?

interface.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QThread>

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC void initialize();

#undef EXTERNC

class Q_DECL_EXPORT SharedLibrary :public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SharedLibrary();

private:
    QCoreApplication * app;
};
```

interface.cpp

```
#include "interface.h"
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)

SharedLibrary::SharedLibrary() {
    int argc = 1;
    char* argv[] = { (char*)"sharedlibrary.lib", NULL };

    app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button("Hello World");
    button.show();
    app->exec();
}

void initialize() {
    new SharedLibrary();
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);
    new SharedLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile my application as an app and run `main` it works just fine. When I compile my application as a lib and run `initialize` it crashes. Interestingly enough, the same exact code works on Linux. Full stack trace below:

```
arithmetic error FLOATING-POINT-INVALID-OPERATION signalled
   [Condition of type FLOATING-POINT-INVALID-OPERATION]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1002E605A3}>)

Backtrace:
  0: ("bogus stack frame")
  1: ("foreign function: CUIDraw")
  2: ("foreign function: _HIThemeCUIDrawWithOptions")
  3: ("foreign function: _HIThemeCUIDrawWithRenderer")
  4: ("foreign function: _HIThemeDrawAppleMenuTitle")
  5: ("foreign function: _ZN13HIMenuBarView8DrawOnceE6CGRectS0_bbP9CGContext")
  6: ("foreign function: _ZN13HIMenuBarView8DrawSelfEsPK9__HIShapeP9CGContext")
  7: ("foreign function: _ZN6HIView12EventHandlerEP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPv")
  8: ("foreign function: _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec")
  9: ("foreign function: _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec")
 10: ("foreign function: SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions")
 11: ("foreign function: _ZN6HIView8SendDrawEsP13OpaqueGrafPtrPK9__HIShapeP9CGContext")
 12: ("foreign function: _ZN6HIView23RecursiveDrawCompositedEPK9__HIShapeS2_jPS_P9CGContexthd")
 13: ("foreign function: _ZN6HIView23RecursiveDrawCompositedEPK9__HIShapeS2_jPS_P9CGContexthd")
 14: ("foreign function: _ZN6HIView14DrawCompositedEsP13OpaqueGrafPtrPK9__HIShapejPS_P9CGContext")
 15: ("foreign function: _ZN6HIView6RenderEjP9CGContext")
 16: ("foreign function: _ZN10WindowData20PrepareForVisibilityEv")
 17: ("foreign function: _ShowHideWindows")
 18: ("foreign function: ShowHide")
 19: ("foreign function: _ZN9MBWindows18GetWindowOnDisplayEjh")
 20: ("foreign function: _ZN15MenuBarInstance15ForEachWindowDoEhU13block_pointerFbP15OpaqueWindowPtrjE")
 21: ("foreign function: _ZN15MenuBarInstance4HideE21MenuBarAnimationStylehhPhh")
 22: ("foreign function: _ZN15MenuBarInstance21UpdateAggregateUIModeE21MenuBarAnimationStylehhh")
 23: ("foreign function: _ZN15MenuBarInstance16ForEachMenuBarDoEU13block_pointerFvPS_E")
 24: ("foreign function: _ZL25UpdateAllAggregateUIModes21MenuBarAnimationStyleh")
 25: ("foreign function: SetSystemUIMode")
 26: ("foreign function: -[NSApplication _setPresentationOptions:instance:flags:]")
 27: ("foreign function: qt_plugin_instance")
 28: ("foreign function: #x8B2BAB2")
 29: ("foreign function: _ZN27QPlatformIntegrationFactory6createERK7QStringRK11QStringListRiPPcS2_")
 30: ("foreign function: _ZN27QPlatformIntegrationFactory6createERK7QStringRK11QStringListRiPPcS2_")
 31: ("foreign function: _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate25createPlatformIntegrationEv")
 32: ("foreign function: _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate21createEventDispatcherEv")
 33: ("foreign function: _ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate4initEv")
 34: ("foreign function: _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate4initEv")
 35: ("foreign function: _ZN19QApplicationPrivate4initEv")
 36: ("foreign function: _ZN13SharedLibraryC2Ev")
 37: ("foreign function: initialize")
 38: (CL-WEBENGINE::INITIALIZE)
 39: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CL-WEBENGINE::INITIALIZE) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 40: (EVAL (CL-WEBENGINE::INITIALIZE))
 41: (SWANK::EVAL-REGION "(cl-webengine::initialize) ..)
 42: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL))
 43: (SWANK-REPL::TRACK-PACKAGE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100318C0AB}>)
 44: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL))
 45: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART "Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request." #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100318C04B}>)
 46: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL))
 47: (SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-SYNTAX-HOOKS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100318C02B}>)
 48: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BUFFER-SYNTAX NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100318C02B}>)
 49: (SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL "(cl-webengine::initialize) ..)
 50: (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(cl-webengine::initialize) ..)
 51: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(cl-webengine::initialize) ..)
 52: (EVAL (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(cl-webengine::initialize) ..)
 53: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(cl-webengine::initialize) ..)
 54: (SWANK::PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
 55: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 56: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 57: (SWANK/SBCL::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1002E680FB}>)
 58: ((FLET SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK :IN "/Users/jmercouris/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20200228.1656/swank/sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-RE..
 59: (SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1002E680FB}>)
 60: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 61: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*STANDARD-INPUT* . #<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-INPUT-STREAM {1002E2F8E3}>)) #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1002E6811B}>)
 62: ((FLET "FORM-FUN-5" :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 63: (SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {1002C0B143}> NIL)
 64: (SWANK-REPL::REPL-LOOP #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {1002C0B143}>)
 65: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::SPAWN-REPL-THREAD))
 66: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::SPAWN-REPL-THREAD) {1002E680DB}>)
 67: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::SPAWN-REPL-THREAD))
 68: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SB-THREAD::NEW-LISP-THREAD-TRAMPOLINE))
 69: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-4" :IN SB-THREAD::NEW-LISP-THREAD-TRAMPOLINE))
 70: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::NEW-LISP-THREAD-TRAMPOLINE))
 71: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-1" :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
 72: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::NEW-LISP-THREAD-TRAMPOLINE) {7A4DE7B}> #<SB-THREAD:MUTEX "thread result lock" owner: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "repl-thr..
 73: (SB-THREAD::NEW-LISP-THREAD-TRAMPOLINE #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1002E605A3}> NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::SPAWN-REPL-THREAD) {1002E6054B}> NIL)
 74: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
 75: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
```

here is what my .pro file looks like:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = webengine
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT += core gui widgets webenginewidgets

# Input
HEADERS += interface.h
SOURCES += interface.cpp
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the only issue but... the documentation for [`QApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) states quite clearly `"Warning: The data referred to by argc and argv must stay valid for the entire lifetime of the QApplication object. In addition, argc must be greater than zero and argv must contain at least one valid character string."`.

Comment: I'll go ahead and add a single argument and see if that makes a difference, thank you.

Comment: @G.M. I made the edits with no noticable changes in behavior

Comment: @jmercouris: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: I am compiling my code like this: 
`qmake`
`make clean`
`make`

I then copy the shared library in my case *.dylib to `/opt/local/lib`.

Comment: I've also added my project file at the bottom of my question if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the answer, at least for my application, apparently I have to change the behavior of the code that interacts with my shared library:

`(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked (:invalid :inexact :overflow) (cl-webengine::run))`

in order to have a successful execution.